# Fast numpy row slicing on a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, numpy-indexing

I have the following issue: I have a matrix `yj` of size `(m,200)` (`m = 3683`), and I have a dictionary that for each key, returns a numpy array of row indices for `yj` (for each key, the size array changes, just in case anyone is wondering).

Now, I have to access this matrix lots of times (around 1M times) and my code is slowing down because of the indexing (I've profiled the code and it takes 65% of time on this step).

Here is what I've tried out:

1. First of all, use the indices for slicing:

```
>> %timeit yj[R_u_idx_train[1]]
10.5 µs ± 79.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The variable `R_u_idx_train` is the dictionary that has the row indices.

2. I thought that maybe boolean indexing might be faster:

```
>> yj[R_u_idx_train_mask[1]]
10.5 µs ± 159 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`R_u_idx_train_mask` is a dictionary that returns a boolean array of size `m` where the indices given by `R_u_idx_train` are set to True.

3. I also tried `np.ix_`

```
>> cols = np.arange(0,200)
>> %timeit ix_ = np.ix_(R_u_idx_train[1], cols); yj[ix_]
42.1 µs ± 353 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

4. I also tried `np.take`

```
>> %timeit np.take(yj, R_u_idx_train[1], axis=0)
2.35 ms ± 88.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And while this seems great, it is not, since it gives an array that is shape `(R_u_idx_train[1].shape[0], R_u_idx_train[1].shape[0])` (it should be `(R_u_idx_train[1].shape[0], 200)`). I guess I'm not using the method correctly.

5. I also tried `np.compress`

```
>> %timeit np.compress(R_u_idx_train_mask[1], yj, axis=0)
14.1 µs ± 124 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

6. Finally I tried to index with a boolean matrix

```
>> %timeit yj[R_u_idx_train_mask2[1]]
244 µs ± 786 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So, is `10.5 µs ± 79.7 ns per loop` the best I can do? I could try to use `cython` but that seems like a lot of work for just indexing...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd also time the pieces, `R_u_idx_train[1]` and `yj[idx]` .  Roughly what's the size of the row index?

Comment: Its not that big. It has ~6000 entries. But calling a dictionary this small should be trivial, right?

Comment: Can you just map results to new dict so avoiding 1 lookup each time like `newdict = {k: yj[R_u_idx_train[k]] for k in R_u_idx_train.keys()}`? Also if keys in your dictionary are consecutive numbers you can use list instead of dict - this can be faster.

Comment: Oh the `newdict` is pretty smart, didn't think about it. And no, my keys are not consecutive (or they need not be), so I think dict is the best data structure for this.

Comment: Actually, that does it for me @V.Ayrat. It sped it up a lot! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: With some quick testing, the time roughly scales with how many elements the indexing returns.  `yj[idx,:]`, ie. `len(idx)*200`.  While fast compared to selecting elements one by one in Python code, it still can't be instantaneous.  The result is a new array with a new databuffer (not a `view`).  `yj[idx]` is the most direct way of doing `numpy` indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very smart solution was given by V.Ayrat in the comments.

```
>> newdict = {k: yj[R_u_idx_train[k]] for k in R_u_idx_train.keys()}
>> %timeit newdict[1]
202 ns ± 6.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Anyway maybe it would still be cool to know if there is a way to speed it up using `numpy`!